# How to compute the sum of degree of two vertexs in each edge in graphx

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx, degrees

I have a graph like this:

```
val vertexArray = Array(
      (1L, ("Alice", 28)),
      (2L, ("Bob", 27)),
      (3L, ("Charlie", 65)),
      (4L, ("David", 42)),
      (5L, ("Ed", 55)))                               
val edges = sc.parallelize(Array(
                 Edge(1L, 2L, ""), 
                 Edge(1L, 3L, ""), 
                 Edge(2L, 4L, ""),
                 Edge(3L, 5L, ""),
                 Edge(2L, 3L, "")))
val graph = Graph(vertexArray, edges)
```

I want to get the sum of degrees of two vertices in each edge.
For example, the node 1L has 2 neighbors and node 2L has 3 neighbors, then the result which i want to get is "1L, 2L, 5".The whole result is:

```
"1L, 2L, 5"
"1L, 3L, 5"
"2L, 4L, 4"
"3L, 5L, 4",
"2L, 3L, 6"
```

How can I implement it in GraphX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can replace each vertex property with its total degree

```
val graphDegrees = graph.outerJoinVertices(graph.degrees)((_,_,deg) => deg.get)
```

And finally, map each triplet and sum up the two vertices' degree

```
val graphSum = graphDegrees.mapTriplets(t => t.srcAttr + t.dstAttr)
```

We can check the result by printing the edges

```
graphSum.edges.collect.foreach(println)
```

Which gives

```
Edge(1,2,5)
Edge(1,3,5)
Edge(2,4,4)
Edge(2,3,6)
Edge(3,5,4)
```

Comment: In addition, I have another question ,its link address is [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251750/how-to-campute-the-jaccard-coefficient-between-the-neighbors-collection-of-two-v), can you solve it? Thanks.